# Binding Microsoft Ribbon Quick Access Buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ribbon

I Use the Microsoft Ribbon. I try to bind the QuickAccessButtons to a Property of my ViewModel, to save the buttons before the application closes and load if after the next start.
My problem is, that I get the Error-Message `Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.` if I try to add a new Button to the QuickAccessToolbar by using the Contextmenu of the RibbonButtons. The Debugger of the Visual Studio stops in a Tab `Source Not Available` with the Content `The call stack contains only external code`.
If I use the ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead, there is no error, but the binding isn't working too.
If I use the direct ItemsSource-Binding and set some RibbonButtons in the binded ObservableCollection as a default, they are shown. So it is the right Property.

My XAML-Code looks like this:

```
<Ribbon Name="ribMain" SelectedIndex="0" Grid.Row="0" IsMinimized="{Binding IsRibbonMinimized}">
        <!-- The Quick-Buttons in the Titlebar of the Window -->
        <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
            <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar ItemsSource="{Binding QuickAccessButtons, Mode=TwoWay}">                    
                <!-- Quick-Access-Buttons here-->
            </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
        </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
        <!-- ... -->
 </Ribbon>
```

the DataContext is set by using

```
<RibbonWindow.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModelMain />
</RibbonWindow.DataContext>
```

and the Property in the ViewModeMain is defined that way:

```
    private ObservableCollection<RibbonButton> _QuickAccessButtons = new ObservableCollection<RibbonButton>(){new RibbonButton()};

    public ObservableCollection<RibbonButton> QuickAccessButtons
    {
        get { return _QuickAccessButtons; }
        set
        {
            _QuickAccessButtons = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QuickAccessButtons");
        }
    }
```

Anyone has an Idea what I can do?